# Docker : How to access the Dockerfile of an image?

Tags: docker

When I run `the command docker images` I get the list as shown below.

[root@hadoop01 myjavadir]# docker images

```
REPOSITORY                   TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
runhelloworld                latest              c49c32235334        18 hours ago        642.2 MB
<none>                       <none>              6eadaac27986        19 hours ago        642.2 MB
<none>                       <none>              ed95cf58873e        25 hours ago        642.2 MB
<none>                       <none>              ebedbfee37fd        25 hours ago        642.2 MB
<none>                       <none>              25453e89b3f0        43 hours ago        0 B
priyankapatil/docker-whale   latest              aa043d321de5        44 hours ago        255.5 MB
helloworld                   latest              aa043d321de5        44 hours ago        255.5 MB
docker-whale                 latest              aa043d321de5        44 hours ago        255.5 MB
java                         latest              3323938eb5a2        9 days ago          642.2 MB
tomcat7                      dockerfile          4b4b09c0dbed        9 days ago          1.289 GB
tomcat7                      dockerfile1         4b4b09c0dbed        9 days ago          1.289 GB
tomcat7                      latest              4b4b09c0dbed        9 days ago          1.289 GB
docker_image                 latest              4b4b09c0dbed        9 days ago          1.289 GB
lastest_docker               latest              4b4b09c0dbed        9 days ago          1.289 GB
tapash1                      latest              4b4b09c0dbed        9 days ago          1.289 GB
<none>                       <none>              866c370a7562        9 days ago          855.3 MB
<none>                       <none>              8ca0c468c6ee        9 days ago          598.8 MB
<none>                       <none>              d5f676fa467b        9 days ago          292.5 MB
<none>                       <none>              459c1c0551e2        9 days ago          265.6 MB
registry                     2                   1fff2b77d9b3        3 weeks ago         224.5 MB
centos                       latest              60e65a8e4030        6 weeks ago         196.6 MB
hello-world                  latest              975b84d108f1        4 months ago        960 B
centos                       centos6             3bbbf0aca359        4 months ago        190.6 MB
docker/whalesay              latest              fb434121fc77        8 months ago        247 MB
```

How can I get access to the dockerfile of an image in this list?

Answer (score 1):

see dockerfile from image from centurylinklabs

https://github.com/CenturyLinkLabs/dockerfile-from-image

`docker history`

on an image will give you the main information, see the doc

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/history/

I had written this short Python script which does a little less than dockerfile-from-image

```
import subprocess
import sys

def main():

    dockid = sys.argv[1]
    args = ['docker', 'history', dockid]
    proc = subprocess.Popen(args=args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    (stdout, stderr) = proc.communicate() 
    lines = stdout.split('\n')[1:-2]
    lines.reverse()
    for line in lines:
        idlayer = line.split(' ')[0]
        args = ['docker', 'inspect', 
                "--format", "'{{ ((index .ContainerConfig.Cmd ) 0) }}'",
                idlayer]
        proc = subprocess.Popen(args=args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        (stdout, stderr) = proc.communicate() 
        print stdout,
        # print idlayer, stdout,

main()
```

Comment: can't get to put the whole Python code correctly displayed, if somebody can help me