# Dockerfile for a newly committed docker image

Tags: image, docker, dockerfile

I downloaded an image of ubuntu os in my system and after about committing 3 images from it(every image has an incremental change from before image), I now have my final image. Now I want the Dockerfile of this final image so that I can include commands like starting service at the start of container.

I have used this command,

`sudo docker commit --change='CMD service apache2 start' 172d6dc34471 server_startup`

to make the apache service start when the container is run. This starts the service in the container but doesn't go inside the container. It just starts the apache and exits to my local environment.

I would like to know how to get the  Dockerfile for my final image so that I can include startup commands.

I have also tried this [dockerfile from image](https://github.com/CenturyLinkLabs/dockerfile-from-image), but its not working. It just throws error that .sock file is missing. I have tried this with both the new image and the parent image that I first downloaded.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why you need to do those incremental changes by hand, and not use Dockerfile directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply, I used the --change argument while committing the image to point to the custom script(which I added within the container with the list of commands to be run at the start) that I want to run when the image is run for the first time.

```
  sudo docker commit --change='ENTRYPOINT ["/test.sh"]' containerId autostart
```

I didn't know much about the dockerfile that everyone is suggesting but it is also a very good solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

`docker history --no-trunc your_image`

it will show you (in reverse order) what has been done

It is less user friendly than dockerfile from image, but it is basically the same thing.

I have somewhere a Python script that does that cleanly, I will check and post it.

Edit: Just this should show a lot

`docker history your_image | docker inspect $(awk ' NR>1 {print $1}')`

Comment: How can i use that to edit the dockerfile? You see i need to to add startup commands to it.

Comment: you have to compare your original Dockerfile and the commands shown by `docker history your_image | docker inspect $(awk ' NR>1 {print $1}')`

Comment: Thats what im trying to say, i dont have a dockerfile for my image as it was committed from another image that i pulled .

Comment: you can do also on that image the same command `docker history your_image | docker inspect $(awk ' NR>1 {print $1}')` and then you compare both

Comment: Im getting a large number meta data about the image. How can i use this to create a dockerfile?

Comment: you just need the instructions that appear, post an extract of the output of the command

Comment: It is a 523 line file . How can i upload it here.

Comment: just display 4 lines, to get an idea

Comment: My python script is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35331988/docker-how-to-access-the-dockerfile-of-an-image/35332319#35332319

Answer (score 1):

As CMD you need to provide a no-daemon program that keeps in foreground. That is not accomplished by `service`.

You should try:

```
sudo docker commit --change='CMD apache2 -DFOREGROUND' 172d6dc34471 server_startup
```